# infowindow show in the same location every time i click on the location point in google maps api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

I don't know why, every my API are getting this error when i click on the place in google maps it show information as simple, but when i click on another, it get the same lat and lng to show information of another place, for example please see the picture below:

[this when i click on Wat Phnom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBHbw.jpg)

and then i click on The Royal Palace

[this when i click on The Royal Palace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSWDX.jpg)

i don't know why it take the same lat and lng tov show infor in my google maps API, or any missing code?

Please help...! and apology me, if my english is not well to explain, Thank you for adavance.

```js
function getid($e){
 return document.getElementById($e);
}

function updatetext($value){
 if(getid('marker-info')!==null){
  getid('marker-info').innerHTML = $value.value;
 }
}

var map;
var marker;

initialize();

function initialize(){
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.5520558,104.9233717);
 var option = {
     zoom: 13,
     center: myLatlng,
     maxZoom: 20,
     minZoom: 8,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
     scrollwheel: true,
     fullscreenControl: true,
     disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
     scaleControl: true,
 };

 map = new google.maps.Map(getid('maps'), option);
}

// Add Marker Event
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'rightclick', function(event){
 addMarker(event.latLng, '../icons/maps.png', true, true);
});

// Add Marker Function
function addMarker(latlng, icon, dragging, showinfo){
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  map:map,
  draggable: dragging,
  icon: icon,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
 });

 

 content = '<div class="marker-form"><div class="head" id="marker-header">Subject Property</div><textarea id="marker-info">'+getid('info-text').value+'</textarea></div>'
 var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 info.setContent(content);
 if(showinfo){
  info.open(map, marker);
 }

 // Add Click Event to Marker
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
  info.open(map, marker);
 });

 var lat = latlng.lat();
    var lng = latlng.lng();

 getid('lat').innerHTML = lat;
 getid('lng').innerHTML = lng;

 // Add Marker Drag Event
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'drag', function(event){
  var lat = event.latLng.lat();
     var lng = event.latLng.lng();

  getid('lat').innerHTML = lat;
  getid('lng').innerHTML = lng;
 });
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500);

body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}

#maps{
 width: 700px;
 height: 700px;
 float: left;
}

.marker-form{
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
}

.marker-form>.head{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 14px;
 border: none;
 width: 100%
}

.marker-form>textarea{
 border: none;
 width: 95%;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 70%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Maps With Single Marker</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="maps.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="maps"></div>
 <div id="lat">Lat</div>
 <div id="lng">Lng</div>

 <textarea id="info-text" onkeyup="updatetext(this);"></textarea>
 
<!-- Script -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="maps.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is because you are using the the same infowindow variable for all infowindows it every time initialize with new marker infowindow content and old one gets replaced with new content. 
so all you have to do is use the different infowindows for all the markers.

example :

```
var cnt=0;
var infoarray=[];
function addMarker(latlng, icon, dragging, showinfo){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map:map,
        draggable: dragging,
        icon: icon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                id=cnt
    });
    cnt++;



    content = '<div class="marker-form"><div class="head" id="marker-header">Subject Property</div><textarea id="marker-info">'+getid('info-text').value+'</textarea></div>';
    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    info.setContent(content);
    if(showinfo){
        info.open(map, marker);
    }
    infoarray.push(info);

    // Add Click Event to Marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        info[this.id].open(map, this);
    });

    var lat = latlng.lat();
    var lng = latlng.lng();

    getid('lat').innerHTML = lat;
    getid('lng').innerHTML = lng;

    // Add Marker Drag Event
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'drag', function(event){
        var lat = event.latLng.lat();
        var lng = event.latLng.lng();

        getid('lat').innerHTML = lat;
        getid('lng').innerHTML = lng;
    });
}
```

Comment: where is this id=cn come from? did you mean id=cnt? #Dhaval Purohit

Comment: yup that it is sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry it still has the same problem. And i think maybe your code is set for array markers. But this maps, I only set one marker only. Can i see your snippet? And sorry for lately reply. :)

Comment: or you have it online anywhere?